# Disable @click event Vuejs 2

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a custom table that serves as a progress bar and added `@click` events on each `td` that will redirect to a specific page. Now, the behavior should be like this:

1. User can't skip forward so the `@click` event to the right items should be disabled.
2. Only `@click` event functions when going back.

Template:

```
<tr>
     <td class="circle col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1"
             @click="goRelationship">Relationship</td>
     <td class="circle col-xs-2"
             @click="goSkills">Skills</td>
     <td class="circle col-xs-2"
             @click="goPurpose">Purpose</td>
     <td class="circle col-xs-2"
             @click="goFit">Fit</td>
     <td class="circle col-xs-2">Submit</td>
 </tr>
```

Script:

```
methods: {
            goRelationship: function () {
                window.location.href = "/v2/review/relationship"
            },
            goSkills: function () {
                window.location.href = "/v2/review/skills"
            },
            goFit: function () {
                window.location.href = "/v2/review/fit"
            },
            goPurpose: function () {
                window.location.href = "/v2/review/purpose"
            }
        }
```

Comment: sorry im trying to understand, can you be more precise? What do want to happen? What will happen If I click a one of them?

Comment: For example, I'm at  `relationship tab` and when I click on the `skills tab`, I need to prevent it to redirect to that unless it's a backward process.

Comment: It's unclear what you actually need. Maybe this helps: there are modifiers for events. for example `@click.prevent="..."` prevents default action. Docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers

Comment: so if Im in skills I can still go back to relationship tab?

Comment: @Kzy, exactly yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to implement some logic to check if navigation steps are active or not. Here is a suggestion:

List of steps:

```
data() {
    return {
        steps: {
            relationship: {
                dependancies: [],
                completed: false,
            },
            skills: {
                dependancies: ['relationship'],
                completed: false,
            },
            fit: {
                dependancies: ['relationship', 'skills'],
                completed: false,
            },
            purpose: {
                dependancies: ['relationship', 'skills', 'fit'],
                completed: false,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A generic go to next step function:

```
goToStep(stepName) {
    if (checkDependanciesCompletion(this.steps[stepName].dependancies)) {
        window.location.href = `/v2/review/${stepName}`
    }
}
```

And a function to check if step that you want to go to is active:

```
function checkDependanciesCompletion(dependencies) {
    let isCompleted = true;

    dependencies.forEach((dep) => {
        if (!this.steps[dep].completed) {
            isCompleted = false;
        }
    });

    return isCompleted;
}
```

Comment: tried inserted the steps, after the methods but it says `module build failed` or I missed something

Comment: It should be in your data function, I have updated the example. The functions should go in your methods object

Comment: Yes, the data steps lacks `colon` :) by the way how about the @click event from the template? should i call `goTostep`?

Comment: Yes, like: `<td class="circle col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1" @click="goToStep('relationship')">Relationship</td>`

Comment: tried all but no luck `checkDependanciesCompletion is not defined`